# Performance penalty of long list in python logging.debug()

Tags: python, logging

How lazy is evaluation in Python? If I have code that looks like

`logging.debug('My very long list: %s' % list(x for x in long_generator))`

and the logging effective level is such that debug messages are ignored, do I incur a performance penalty for having this line?

Comment: There is no lazy evaluation in Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will not be lazily evaluated, but Python logging has a solution to this problem: [`isEnabledFor()`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#optimization).

```
if logger.isEnabledFor(logging.DEBUG):
    logger.debug('My very long list: %s' % list(x for x in long_generator))
```

Your list will be built and formatted **only** if logger's level is higher than `DEBUG`.

Answer (score 2):

You will have a performance penalty because `list(x for x in long_generator)` will be created before calling `logging.debug()` even if debug messages are ignored.

There is no lazy evaluation in Python. Every line is evaluated/executed before the next line. It means that expressions are evaluated when they are bound to variables.